# Running wget command with maven

Tags: maven, ftp, maven-3, wget

I have this command that is working,

but I want to run it with maven.

> wget -r ftp://user:passwors@foo.bar.com/DIR_DUMP/*.dmp

can anyone show me the how the pom.xml will look like?

B.T.W I tried this pom but I couldn't get large file:

```
<plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.8</version>
        <configuration>
            <target>
                <ftp action="get"
                     server="192.168.1.1"
                     remotedir="remoteDir"
                     userid="anonymous"
                     password="anonymous">
                    <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}">
                        <include name="**/*.*"/>
                    </fileset>
                </ftp>
            </target>
        </configuration>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>commons-net</groupId>
                <artifactId>commons-net</artifactId>
                <version>1.4.1</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.apache.ant</groupId>
                <artifactId>ant-commons-net</artifactId>
                <version>1.8.1</version>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </plugin>
```

Comment: do you receive any error messages?

Comment: No,
I let it run for 2 hours but nothing happened. using wget command it take less than an hour.